# HP Pavilion 14 very slow on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, graphics, intel-graphics, performance

I've recently bought a new laptop (HP Pavilion 14) and decided to replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit).

The problem is that it's now so much slower than before. It boots very fast but everything is choppy and laggy. Even typing this question, the characters take ages to appear on screen. Dragging a window around is also very slow. Youtube videos are choppy and not smooth at all.

Here are the laptop specs:

- CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8
- RAM: 8 gb
- 256 gb SSD
- Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)

The system and drivers are up to date according to Ubuntu. There are not addition drivers available to download either. However, I've got a feeling that it's something to do with the graphics card.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Choppy and laggy" could have many possible causes, so rule some frequent causes out before assigning blame. Open a terminal. Use the `top` application to determine if your CPU is being overtaxed (and by what). Use the `free` application to determine if you are low on RAM.

Comment: @user535733 My bad, should have included this in the initial post. I checked CPU and RAM usage and it's only using a small part of it but it's still slow. Also, it wasn't slow on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm interested in the answers to this question. I bought HP Pavilion and installed Ubuntu 18 to it, but it was painfully slow (even though it's a brand new computer)

Comment: I ended up getting rid of mine, not worth the hassle.